# HTML - Replace values on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make a quiz where it displays one question at a time, and on the "submit answer" button click, the button validates the answer (either right or wrong) and also replaces the previous question with a new one.
What I want to know is; how do you replace the question on button click?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
                    <div id="quiz" style="display:none;">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <h1>Quiz</h1>
                                <p id="question">Question 01 : this is where the queston will go</p>
                                <form name="feedback">
                                    <input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt_1"> ans 1 <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt_2"> ans 2 <br>
                                    <input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt_3"> ans 3 <br>

                                    <p><span id="err" style="display: none;color: red;">Select an option</span></p>
                                    <button id="submit_btn" value="Submit" onClick="submit()"></button>
                                </form>
                                <br>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I've tried using an if statement, but it didnt work. I would greatly appreciate your help as my knowledge on html and js are very basic.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? The onclick event? The submit() function? And where exactly is the submit() function?

Comment: I think i forgot to include the function here. The only thing that works is the validation though. I want to replace "question" with a new one on the submit button click, as well as change the radio button values to the answer options of their corresponding question.

Comment: Is there any server side functionality or is it only javascript + html? If you paste the submit() function it would be helpful to better understand your problem.

Comment: No it is ONLY html and js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what your code should look like:

```js
var questions = ["Question 1", "Question 2", "Question 3"]; //Array containing all your questions. Make sure to include the question that's already being displayed

var possibleAnswers = [
  ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3"],
  ["answer 1", "answer 2", "answer 3"]
]; //An array of arrays containing the answers to every question. Make sure the answers are in the same order as the questions

var currentQuestion = 0;

var question = $("#question");
var answers = $(".answer");
var button = $("#submit_btn");
var buttonAction = function() {
  currentQuestion++;
  question.text(questions[currentQuestion]);

  for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    answers[i].textContent = possibleAnswers[currentQuestion][i];
  }
};

button.on("click", buttonAction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="quiz">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <h1>Quiz</h1>
      <p id="question">Question 01 : this is where the queston will go</p>
      <form name="feedback">
        <input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt_1"> <span class="answer">ans 1 </span><br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt_2"> <span class="answer">ans 2 </span> <br>
        <input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt_3"> <span class="answer">ans 3 </span> <br>

        <p><span id="err" style="display: none;color: red;">Select an option</span></p>
        <button id="submit_btn" value="Submit" onClick="submit()"></button>
      </form>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
```

List of changes:

- Removed `style="display: none;"` from form tag
- Added JavaScript to take care of changing the questions and answers
- Placed the answers between span tags and added a class of "answer" to them to make them easily accesible

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the content with this :

```
function replace(){

var obj = document.getElementById("question");
obj.innerHTML="the_next_question";

}
```

if you need to get the element by the className you can use :

```
document.getElementsByClassName("question")[0];
```